# How to play video in a frame without cutting video using MPMoviePlayer

Tags: objective-c, ios7, mpmovieplayercontroller

Is there any way to fill video without stretching and cutting the video ?

1- MPMovieScalingModeFill - its stretching video. 
2- MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill - its cutting video.
3- MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit - its shooing video in centre and showing black area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Think about it! The MPMoviePlayerController's view is not the same aspect (ratio height to width) as the movie. So to make it fit, either you must cut some off (of either height or width), or you must letterbox it (black area) with one dimension being too small, or you must distort.

You should do the opposite: size the MPMoviePlayerController's view to fit the aspect of the movie!

Comment: Yes, well, I've written a whole book with this kind of stuff in it. Here's the example code from the book: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch15p659moviePlayer/ch28p927moviePlayer/ViewController.m Notice how I wait for the `MPMovieNaturalSizeAvailableNotification` and then call my `finishSetup` method to set the view to the same size ratio as the movie.